# KeyError: records when trying to return record count from API

Tags: python, api, keyerror, hypixel-api

I am trying to check how many records a player has using the Hypixel API friends endpoint (api.hypixel.net/friends)

It keeps giving me a key error when trying to count the records. Here is what the API gives me:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "records": [{"_id":"5806841c0cf247f13be18b9d","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"976129e438b54a839944b1c0703d4da3","started":1476822044856},{"_id":"59589dde0cf250df95af825e","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"2c5bfce120c04ef1bfb3b798fe0d650e","started":1498979806692},{"_id":"5a444d820cf2604c12e0f6bd","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"ea703151981a409f8d0ff7cb782ab1c1","started":1514425730370},{"_id":"5aa595800cf24bd1104381cc","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"27af346e5bde40f0a665e808a331576f","started":1520801152354},{"_id":"5e2511f90cf289be2d0ea273","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"24a90aca074c4293a656f5fda047f816","started":1579487737061},{"_id":"5e36448c0cf2174287f94af7","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","started":1580614796544},{"_id":"5e3f54190cf2ab010c5a21ce","uuidSender":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","uuidReceiver":"63817f05823945a2b58f4ba1de5589a3","started":1581208601957},{"_id":"55bec5e0c8f2e017bca39176","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1438565856136},{"_id":"55e21268c8f21846db2f2566","uuidSender":"8fca5ebf02f74a369b13f3407ad4a9bc","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1440879208434},{"_id":"56c26b190cf2d1a91ec25e83","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1455581977070},{"_id":"5755edc20cf2db67507e3a2e","uuidSender":"0ce4597de5484c0e82a067fa0bf171df","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1465249218466},{"_id":"5851ed8d0cf2b9563974034d","uuidSender":"d3dd0059775e46b1b1a63b94a10d2450","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1481764237412},{"_id":"5d087a1f0cf2d7aebbf96fd6","uuidSender":"d6695d1ea7ae480bb2129a3b7d0269ad","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1560836639346},{"_id":"5d703a880cf299e651b71cbb","uuidSender":"cbd9e9009ee94d159d52dff284ad7bf8","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1567636104118},{"_id":"5deeff7f0cf2d87bd75df1a0","uuidSender":"c53c4524ad174fd78134223fddedc484","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1575944063334},{"_id":"5e0638f20cf24f983d2cb02c","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1577466098097},{"_id":"5e1e70e70cf2795e4f1322be","uuidSender":"85090a8b495d4856817fd6df1d4da0bd","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1579053287837},{"_id":"5e1fbe4b0cf2795e4f14a36f","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1579138635859},{"_id":"5e25910d0cf2a892e569db39","uuidSender":"63ac73044aca4b2f908baff858cf34b9","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1579520269103},{"_id":"5e712f890cf2d292e1148ba6","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1584476041946},{"_id":"5e819f550cf2675e4372109b","uuidSender":"8cd38d8f97a24090a43e2e0ce898c521","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1585553237302},{"_id":"5e82c5ad0cf2675e437308aa","uuidSender":"d618457dd6044256bdb287b0df8137d4","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1585628589448},{"_id":"5eae3e420cf26efdbd55b592","uuidSender":"a936c3468bec4a2685199a398212b62d","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1588477506714},{"_id":"5ebd9da40cf22f431e9164d8","uuidSender":"1nmHNU1mERJEG452cx1FazPx3RpAuZ9vW","uuidReceiver":"71ef88df5f7e482fb472f344965beba8","started":1589484964296}]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_friend_count(name):
    getUUID = f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{name}"

    res = requests.get(getUUID)
    data = res.json()

    if data["id"] is None:
        return None

    returnUuid = (data["id"])

    url1 = f"https://api.hypixel.net/friends?key={API_KEY}&uuid=" + returnUuid

    res2 = requests.get(url1)
    data2 = res2.json()

    if data2["records"] is None:
        return None

    friend_count = len(data["records"])

    return "Friends: " + friend_count
```

getUUID gets the UUID from the requested username and then uses the UUID to get the players Hypixel stats.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Mojang API: https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API
Hypixel API: https://github.com/HypixelDev/PublicAPI/tree/master/Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just forget to `request.get(url1)`?

In any case, from the mojang API doc, it seems the endpoint you query (https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/) never returns a "records" key ... thus the error when you do `if data["records"] is None`

Comment: I just noticed, i fixed that. But i still get the same error.

Command Raised An Exception: KeyError: 'records'

Comment: Did you fix it in there too : friend_count = len(data["records"]) ?